# When does a matrix have only positive eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

When does a matrix has only positive eigenvalues?

I know that you can say if the eigenvalues are real or not by saying if the matrix is selfadjoint or skewadjoint, but how can you prove that has only positive eigenvalues?

Problem:

> Let $A$ ∈ $\Bbb C^{n×n}$. Show spec($A$*$A$) ⊂ $[0, ∞).$

Comment: In general, we have to calculate the eigenvalues. In some special cases, we can see it easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A^\ast A v=\lambda v,\,v\ne 0$ then $\lambda =\frac{v^\ast A^\ast Av}{v^\ast v}$ is a ratio of squared lengths, i.e. $\lambda\ge 0$. As for the question of when matrics are positive-definite, there are [several tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations).

Comment: Is A*A a skew or self-adjoint matrix ?

Comment: @Kai It's self-adjoint, but more to the point note $v^\ast A^\ast Av=(Av)^\ast Av$ is the squared length of $Av$.